# How to determine which Radio Button is selected in Form with multiple button groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a form with two groups of radio buttons.  They all have the same name, but in the case where a certain type of radio button is selected, I want to change the content before the next submission.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="ahBkM" id="ahBkM" name="key" class="spam">
  <input type="radio" value="ahBkA" id="ahBkA" name="key" class="eggs">
  <input type="radio" value="ahBkB" id="ahBkB" name="key" class="eggs">
  <input type="radio" value="ahBkC" id="ahBkC" name="key" class="eggs">
</form>
```

If the form is sumitted with the first radio button is selected (class spam), I don't need to do anything special.  But if any class eggs button is selected when the form is submitted, then I need to update the DOM with data coming back from the AJAX POST.

**I'm looking for a truth conditional on whether eggs was selected** for the POST (I can put the conditional in the AJAX success function), and if so then I have some code to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('input[name=key].eggs:checked').length > 0){
  // an egg group is selected.
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: Sorry, change to use `[name=key]` not `[type=submit]`.

Answer (score 2):

Search for checked eggs:

```
$(".eggs:checked").length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:checked` selector.
e.g:

```
var checkedRadio = $("[name='key']:checked");
var checkedVal = checkedRadio.val();
if(checkedVal == "eggs"){
  //Do Something 
} else{

}
```